# How can I limit PHP code to a specific folder?

Tags: php, directory, limit

I'm setting up a webserver for my students to try their php code on.
On the webserver I'll have a folder for each student and I don't want code that the students upload to their folder to change/read/execute files outside of the students folder.

Is there anyway to address this problem without setting up a VPS for each student?

Comment: I think the best way will be htaccess, since php code can only run with a `.php` or `.phtml` file extension you can just make sure that files ending in those extensions can run in `folder_for_students` and outside of the folder will submit a bad request http code

Comment: not really a programming questions. this is more server configuration. but you could try a chroot jail

Comment: Possibly use Runkit_Sandbox from PECL?

Comment: Perhaps something like [Codeanywhere](https://codeanywhere.com)? Free plan should be enough for a student.

Comment: @iam-decoder The concern here is one student's program could read the source of another. There's a lot of chaos a renegade PHP script can cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marc B suggested a chroot jail - but like VPS, this effectively entails running at least seperate FPM pools for each student.

A simpler solution would be to use the open_basedir functionality to constrain scripts to their own directory tree. You can enable this in the webserver config on a per directory basis - but I don't think there is an easy way to map the paths calculated by mod_userdir, i.e. you'll need lots of

```
 <Directory "/home/Gurgy/public_html">
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/Gurgy/"
 </Directory>

 <Directory "/home/MarcB/public_html">
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/MarcB/"
 </Directory>

 ...
```

(This might merit a further question on Serverfault to see if anyone knows a better way of solving this more specific problem).

There are some loopholes which allow you to get access to files outside the open_basedir restriction. The symlink bug is fixed, but not sure about the IMAP holes. Best to use a recent, patched version of PHP with Suhosin and do some further research.

Having said that - unless its a very short course, you might want to provide them ewach with a VM image which they can then use to explore other aspects of service provision.

Comment: A combination of this and [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) might do it.

Comment: Would this setting be set in a .htaccess file?

Comment: @tadman: using suphp along with a restrictive permissions policy would be enough, no need to use open_basedir, but suphp only runs as CGI - performance sucks.

Comment: @Gurgy: a bit silly to apply the constraint in a file the students will have access to.

Comment: seriously...I just made all the effort of using the mpm_itk_module to make all virtual hosts run as a different user limited to their folders. This is so much easier, and more effective!

Comment: @Pete: as long you can install (potentially 3rd party) modules and don't try to bridge your sessions that is a viable solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Is [that](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) what you're looking for? If yes, this is a `php.ini` setting. In order to put this into your web server config in every virtualhost section, we need to know:

1. what web server do you use
2. how do you configure virtual host for every student

If there is a separate configuration and virtualhost for every student, consider adding

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/path/to/this/student/folder"
```

to the virthost config